# How do I transfer ERC20 tokens (GNT,OMG, etc) from a cold wallet to another account (or exchange) using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, golem, omisego

I want to transfer ERC20 (standard) tokens from a basic ethereum account to an exchange or to another account. How do I do that without using a GUI like Mist?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48127335/395974

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 0:** Install geth, start geth (with "--unlock 0xYOURACCOUNT"), sync the blockchain, open up a geth terminal in another window with "geth attach".

**Step 1:** Save the ERC20 ABI to a variable. This is the interface for interacting with the token contract.

```
var omisegoAbi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_releaseTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintTimelocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
```

**Step 2:** Create the contract variable using the web3 contract method:

```
var omisegoContract = web3.eth.contract(omisegoAbi).at('0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07'); // 0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07 is the omisego contract addr. Other tokens will have different addresses
```

**Optional step**, check an account balance (# of OMG tokens for this acct):

```
web3.fromWei(omisegoContract.balanceOf("0xYOURACCOUNT"),"ether");
```

or check all of your accounts in the .ethereum/keystore directory

```
eth.accounts.forEach(function(e,i){console.log("eth.accounts["+i+"]: " + "\tbalance:" + web3.fromWei(omisegoContract.balanceOf(eth.accounts[i]),"ether") + " OMG")})
```

**Step 3:** Send a small amount of the token (here, 1) to the destination address.

```
omisegoContract.transfer("0xDESTINATIONADDRESS",web3.toWei(1,"ether"),{from:"0xGASPAYINGADDRESS"});// here, 0xGASPAYINGADDRESS is the account from which to pay gas to make this tx. Probably the same as the source address.
```

**Step 4:** Transfer the rest. Same command as above with a greater value

Comment: I've been looking all over the web for this. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are my hero and I love you

Answer (score 1):

This is awesome, but for some reason its trying to send all the tokens. Where do you control the amount?
 `,web3.toWei(1,"ether")` isn't this part for the ether payment?

Comment: The only thing that `web3.toWei(1,"ether")` does is multiply 1 with 10^18. This is because the amount in the `transfer` function must be specified in base units (E.g. number of Wei if it was Ether). So if the ERC-20 you send does not have 18 decimals, you need to change this code or you will send orders of magnitude more or less tokens than you think.