# invoking a ethereum TokenERC20 contract from terminal: Transfer ethers or Tokens on private ethereum blockchain

Tags: private-blockchain, tokens, contract-invocation, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

I have set up a private ethereum blockchain on 3 different nodes.

Then I deployed following standard TokenERC20 contract on blockchain using ethereum wallet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) public; }

contract TokenERC20 {
    // Public variables of the token
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals = 18;
    // 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    // This creates an array with all balances
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    // This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    // This notifies clients about the amount burnt
    event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

    /**
     * Constrctor function
     *
     * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
     */
    function TokenERC20(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        string tokenSymbol
    ) public {
        totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
    }

    /**
     * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
     */
    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
        // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
        require(_to != 0x0);
        // Check if the sender has enough
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        // Check for overflows
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value > balanceOf[_to]);
        // Save this for an assertion in the future
        uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
        // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        // Add the same to the recipient
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
        assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
     *
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    /**
     * Transfer tokens from other address
     *
     * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` in behalf of `_from`
     *
     * @param _from The address of the sender
     * @param _to The address of the recipient
     * @param _value the amount to send
     */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Set allowance for other address and notify
     *
     * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens in your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
     *
     * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
     * @param _value the max amount they can spend
     * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
     */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        public
        returns (bool success) {
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
     *
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
        totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
        Burn(msg.sender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Destroy tokens from other account
     *
     * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
     *
     * @param _from the address of the sender
     * @param _value the amount of money to burn
     */
    function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
        totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
        Burn(_from, _value);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then on a geth console, I synced this contract using:

```
var abi = contractInterface  //i gave actual interface here
var address = contractAddress   //i gave actual address where contract is deployed
var adder1 = eth.contract(abi).at(address)
```

Then printing `adder1` on geth console shows:

```
> adder1
{
  abi: [{
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "name",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "approve",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "totalSupply",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "transferFrom",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "decimals",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "burn",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "balanceOf",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "burnFrom",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "symbol",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "transfer",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "approveAndCall",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "allowance",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "constructor"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "Transfer",
      type: "event"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "Burn",
      type: "event"
  }],
  address: "0xA8113a44aCC20305ce9f2Cd7CC067562b8f54d6c",
  transactionHash: null,
  Burn: function(),
  Transfer: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  allowance: function(),
  approve: function(),
  approveAndCall: function(),
  balanceOf: function(),
  burn: function(),
  burnFrom: function(),
  decimals: function(),
  name: function(),
  symbol: function(),
  totalSupply: function(),
  transfer: function(),
  transferFrom: function()
}
```

**Untill here everything seems to be working fine. Now when i try to use transfer function as follows:**

```
adder1.transfer("0x542b2103c2cf18ce6e22d5099bee3db32e984641",33000000000000000000)
```

It gives me error:

```
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3756:20
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
```

or even if I do:

```
adder1.transferFrom(eth.accounts[0],"0x542b2103c2cf18ce6e22d5099bee3db32e984641",33000000000000000000)
```

I get error:

```
Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3756:20
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
```

It doesn't even give any clue for debugging.

---

> Question: Can someone please help in how I can send ethers or Token
>   using above deployed contract from terminal.

---

fyi `TokenERC20` can be found here: [https://www.ethereum.org/token][1]

Any help or better understanding in this context is most welcome.

I have spent hours on this but couldn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a working answer myself:

Refer to this: [How do I transfer ERC20 tokens (GNT,OMG, etc) from a cold wallet to another account (or exchange) using geth](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/how-do-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-gnt-omg-etc-from-a-cold-wallet-to-another-acco)

And this is what I did:

```
var abi = contractInterface  
var address = contractAddress   
var adder1 = eth.contract(abi).at(address)

var fromAccount = "0x7a52a05a2a2f3c9ed8b1297db5399c0c3adfa5c2".toLowerCase()

var destAccount = "0x542b2103c2cf18ce6e22d5099bee3db32e984641".toLowerCase()

adder1.transfer(destAccount,web3.toWei(20,"ether"),{from:fromAccount})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlock account and set it to default will solve your issue

[image]