# Web3 Contract.balanceOf is not a function

Tags: web3js, contract-development, tokens, contract-invocation

I have read [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/how-do-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-gnt-omg-etc-from-a-cold-wallet-to-another-acco) helpful SO answer about sending ERC20 contracts, but it seems that the Web3 docs and API have changed dramatically since then. I am trying to get the balance of a smart contract using Contract.balanceOf, but I am  receiving errors saving that `balanceOf` is no longer a function.

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("xx.xxx.xx.xx"));

var omisegoAbi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"mintingFinished","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mint","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"finishMinting","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_amount","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_releaseTime","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintTimelocked","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Mint","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"MintFinished","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}];
var omisegoContract = web3.eth.Contract(omisegoAbi, '0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07'); // 0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07 is the omisego contract addr. Other tokens will have different addresses

balance = web3.fromWei(omisegoContract.balanceOf("0xb8fd65fc6919c5b97453eaba6b895144597985b2"),"ether");
```

My error is that the `Contract.balanceOf` function cannot be found. How do I correctly get the balance of my ERC20 contract?

`TypeError: omisegoContract.balanceOf is not a function`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On web3.js v1.x, you should fix the following:

1. Change `web3.eth.Contract` to `new web3.eth.Contract`
2. Change `omisegoContract.balanceOf` to `await omisegoContract.methods.balanceOf`

Of course, the 2nd bullet implies that this line should be executed from an `async function`.

Comment: Thanks ill give this a shot in about 20 minutes when I'm at my computer

Comment: Does it need to be in an async function?

Comment: @BarneyChambers: A contract method returns a `Promise` object when called from an off-chain (web3-client) script. You need to resolve this `Promise` object in order to obtain the actual value (in this case, the balance). One way to do this is by awaiting for the contract method to complete, which, due to the use of `await` must be done from an `async` function.