# Geth + Web3 | web3.eth.getAccounts() returns undefined

Tags: web3js, erc-20, contract-invocation, accounts

I have follow [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/how-do-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-gnt-omg-etc-from-a-cold-wallet-to-another-acco) SO answer for sending ERC20 tokens from 1 address to another. I am running into an issue where I am receiving an error that my `from address` is invalid

`Error: Error: WalletMiddleware - Invalid "from" address.`

The from address works just fine when I use the web3 function `contract.balanceOf`, so I am not sure why it says my address is invalid

**Here is my code:**

```
 contract.transfer(
    '0x002FaCf5B2e8441c7ECb4eb6dCfD9C7b46320c97', //toaddress
    web3.toWei(1, "ether"),      //send 1 token
    {
        from:'0xb8fd65fc6919c5b97453eaba6b895144597985b2' //fromaddress
    }, function(err, transactionHash)
    {
        if(!err)
        {
            console.log(transactionHash);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you use `getAccounts() ?` Your question does not seem to match with your description, please make the connection between those two points.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see where web3.eth.getAccounts() is used in your code, but this is javascript promise and you might wanna use it this way to get the accounts:

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, accounts) {
if(error) {
    console.log(error);
} else {
    console.log(accounts);
}
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I receive an empty array from `accounts`